# How to get the inner most type of a n-nested vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, nested

I need to get the inner type of a n-nested vector.  For Example:

```
type a;                          //base_type of a = type
std::vector<type> b;             //base_type of b = type
std::vector<std::vector<type>> c;//base_type of c = type
```

and so on.  I tried using a wrapper, but this results in a compiler error.

```
template<typename T1>
struct base_type : T1::value_type { };

template<typename T1>
struct base_type<std::vector<T1>> {
    using type = typename base_type<T1>::value_type;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Both of your cases are wrong.

Your base case should be the non-`vector` case. For a non-`vector`, there is no `::value_type`. You just want the type:

```
template <typename T>
struct base_type {
    using type = T;
};
```

For your recursive case, `base_type`'s "result" type is named `type`. Not `value_type`, so we have to use that here:

```
template<typename T>
struct base_type<std::vector<T>> {
    using type = typename base_type<T>::type;
};
```

which we can simplify to just:

```
template<typename T>
struct base_type<std::vector<T>> 
: base_type<T>
{ };
```