# Constrain the key and value inner type of a nested std::map

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, stdmap, c++-concepts

Originally, I wanted to constrain the inner type of a nested `std::vector`, to be, for example, an int or a std::string. I was able to achieve this using C++20's concepts and the following stack overflow ticket: [How to get the inner most type of a n-nested vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960715/how-to-get-the-inner-most-type-of-a-n-nested-vector)

```cpp
// trait to get the innermost type
template <typename T>
struct inner_type
{
    using type = T;
};

// vector specialization
template <typename T>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = typename inner_type<T>::type;
};

// alias for convenience
template<typename T>
using inner_type_t = typename inner_type<T>::type;

template<typename T>
concept IsInnerTypeInt = (std::same_as<inner_type_t<T>, int>);

template<typename Arg>
requires IsInnerTypeInt<Arg>
auto bar(Arg arg)
{

}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> intvec{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> intvec_vec{{1,2}, {3, 4}};

    bar(intvec);
    bar(intvec_vec);
}
```

So far, so good. The problem comes when I want to add a specialisation for a nested std::map, to constrain the inner type of both keys and values:

```cpp
// map value specialization
template<typename Key, typename Val>
struct inner_type<std::map<Key, Val>>
{
    using type = typename inner_type<Val>::type;
};

// map key specialization
template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct inner_type<std::map<Key, Value>>
{
    using type = typename inner_type<Key>::type;
};
```

Doing this, I get a redefinition error, since the function signatures are the same. How can I achieve this? I have experimented with using template template parameters, but if I am honest, I am not sure if this is the right path to go down.

Comment: What use is this "inner" type?  It's hard to see why you might need it.  Why is `bar()` useful with `int`, `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, etc. but not other types?

Comment: your issue seems to be a odd notion of "inner_type". If you stick with `value_type` then it works exactly the same for `std::map` as it does for `std::vector` because they both have a `value_type` member alias

Comment: I've clarified in the question, it must be a nested map. E.g. std::map<std::vector<int>, int>, or std::map<int, std::vector<int>>, or std::vector<std::map<int, std::vector<std::map<int, int>>>>

Comment: Should `bar` accept or reject `std::map<int, double>`? You will need to handle a sequence of types, not a singular type.

Answer (score 3):

You can constrain the `std::map` specialization's `Key` and `Val` to have the same inner type, and define inner type to be either

```
 template<typename Key, typename Val>
    requires std::same_as<typename inner_type<Key>::type, 
                          typename inner_type<Val>::type>
  struct inner_type<std::map<Key, Val>>
  {
    using type = typename inner_type<Val>::type;
  };
```

Comment: I like this solution, but would it be possible to extend this solution so that Key and Value can have different inner types? E.g., this won't work:     std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> m;
    bar(m);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do such contraptions to deduce the internal types (element types) of containers.

All standard container have a `::value_type` trait. In the case of associative containers (such as `std::map`), you have `::key_type` and `::mapped_type` as well.

You can use concepts on top of this.

For `std::map<K, V>` be aware that the `value_type` is `std::pair<K const, V>` (`const`!).

I am not very good at concepts but this captures the idea:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<string>
#include<map>

template<typename Map>
requires std::is_same_v<typename Map::value_type, std::pair<int const, std::string>>
auto bar(Map const& arg) {}

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    bar(m); // ok

    std::map<int, double> n;
    bar(n); // not ok
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W9xb4W5TG

**Note added after clarification:** If you need to accept a nested container type, you can still use the technique, but I would rely more on `key_type` and `mapped_type` if you want to ensure that the intermediate container is a `std::map` or at least `std::map`-like.

For the case of `vector<map<map<int, vector<int>>, vector<int>>>` for example, it could be:

```
template<typename NestedContainer>
requires (
       std::is_same_v<typename NestedContainer::value_type::key_type::key_type, int>
    && std::is_same_v<typename NestedContainer::value_type::key_type::mapped_type::value_type, int>
    && std::is_same_v<typename NestedContainer::value_type::mapped_type::value_type, int>
)
auto bar(NestedContainer const& arg) {}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::map<std::map<int, std::vector<int>>, std::vector<int>>> c;
    bar(c); // ok

    std::map<int, double> d;
    bar(d); // not ok
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nqYzvfx63

Comment: I believe the OP asked for `vector<map<map<int, vector<int>>, vector<int>>>` to work.

Comment: Correct. in your example, this does not work:     std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> q;
    bar(q); It must accept arbitrarily nested vectors and maps

Comment: I've clarified in the question that it must be a nested std::map and std::vector.
Here is a link to getting the type of a nested vector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960715/how-to-get-the-inner-most-type-of-a-n-nested-vector

Comment: Oh, I see; things can be arbitrarily nested. Well, yes, you can have this an replace `value_type`  by `most_nested_value` or something. However, good luck writing the implementation of the function that works under all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The redefinition error you're encountering occurs because you're trying to specialize the inner_type struct twice for the same template class std::map. Unfortunately, C++ does not allow partial specialization for individual members of a class template, which is what you're trying to do.

Instead of specializing inner_type for std::map in two separate ways, you can achieve your goal by introducing a new trait to handle nested types, and then specialize that trait for both std::vector and std::map. Here's how you can do it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

// trait to get the innermost type
template <typename T>
struct inner_type {
    using type = T;
};

// vector specialization
template <typename T>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T>> {
    using type = typename inner_type<T>::type;
};

// map value specialization
template <typename Key, typename Val>
struct inner_type<std::map<Key, Val>> {
    using type = typename inner_type<Val>::type;
};

// map key specialization
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct inner_type<std::pair<Key, Value>> {
    using type = typename inner_type<Key>::type;
};

template<typename T>
using inner_type_t = typename inner_type<T>::type;

template<typename T>
concept IsInnerTypeInt = std::same_as<inner_type_t<T>, int>;

template<typename Arg>
requires IsInnerTypeInt<Arg>
auto bar(Arg arg) {
    // Your implementation here
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> intvec{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> intvec_vec{{1,2}, {3, 4}};
    std::map<std::string, int> map_str_int{{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}};
    std::map<int, std::string> map_int_str{{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}};

    bar(intvec);
    bar(intvec_vec);
    // bar(map_str_int); // This will not compile due to the constraint
    // bar(map_int_str); // This will not compile due to the constraint

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the new inner_type<std::pair<Key, Value>> specialization handles the case of extracting the inner type of the key for std::map, allowing you to avoid redefining the entire inner_type structure.

Please note that I've commented out the calls to bar with std::map arguments because you have a constraint that only allows inner types of int. If you want to handle different types of inner values in the map, you would need to create additional constraints or overloads for those cases.

Comment: I don't see how this would work, it accepts any `std::map<X, int>` where X is not an `int`.